# Batch Data-driven variables Photoshop and centering text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

i use data driven for batch many files but i have problem on the final files the text are not centered :(
My original template are perfectly centered but when i export using batch all text are not centered so it look very bad the name has not the same length but the letters have only one character so i don't understand why on final file text is moved.
see my screenshot and sorry for my english :p[image]

Answer (score 1):

The swash in the first letter of the name is the cause.  You can try it with another font, try something like Palatino or Delphin No. 1 those fonts could very well work for you.

Alternatively you could calculate the length of the swash and offset the position accordingly. You may end up with quite a few that don't apply.

Your best solution is to use a font that does not have so wide a swash that causes the offset.

Comment: The problem happen also on the letter I need to use A to Z so normally it shouldn't move for the letter. For the name i understand that the font can cause the issue but why also on single letter??

Comment: The reason for this is because the difference in width for the uppercase letter and the lowercase letter is quite large. Also the width for all letters are not the same. If you have already centered the letter to the canvas and centre justified the text, then you will have to manually align every name.